# How to stop Network Manager from continually prompting for wireless password

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, wpa2

How can I stop NetworkManager from continuously asking for the wireless password when trying to reconnect after the connection is temporarily dropped?

Unlike [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64903/network-manager-asks-for-wireless-password-continually), this happens for me without suspending. My wireless `WPA2` connection might drop a couple times, and NetworkManager will automatically reconnect. However, eventually NetworkManager will start prompting for the password, which is already filled in. Clicking <kbd>Show password</kbd> confirms it's already the correct password, and clicking <kbd>Connect</kbd> without changing anything also successfully connects.

Why is it doing this, and how do I stop it?

Comment: Good question — this, coupled with less-then-stellar drivers, makes for some infuriating moments. Like leaving your PC on overnight and having to close about fifty such dialog boxes first thing in the morning.

Comment: You might want to make use of my answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/595084/wireless-password-not-protected). You will need to use 'Automatically connect' option, but then, to disable connection uncheck 'Enable Networking'.

Comment: Duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/q/19137/51272

Comment: I can't believe that this hasn't been fixed yet... Ubuntu 16.04 on my Thinkpad x200, and Ubuntu 17.04 on my desktop (using Gigabyte GC-WB867D-I) exhibit this infuriating problem. My macbook pro, which sits just 50cm away from them works flawlessly.

Comment: Please go to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1633413, sign up, and click on "Does this bug affect you?" currently it is unassigned and has no importance, since they think only 3 people experience this awful behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try restarting the network manager:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Comment: This does not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

May I suggest that you run in a terminal

```
nm-tool
```

That will give you a list of wireless access points that are in range, the frequency that they are transmitting on and the signal strength.

Your wireless access point/router could be using the same frequency as another access point and if they are at the same or of similar strength it could explain why your connection is dropping. It may also mean that network manager after failing to connect to your access is now trying to connect to this other one. And that is why it is asking for a password. You have the right password for your access point but not for the access point that network manager is trying to connect to.

You may need to enter your router's set up program and select a different channel or frequency.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this isn't the problem. I was initially using a frequency in use by other networks. However, I switched to a frequency not in use, and was still repeatedly prompted for my password.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Besides, it happens even when the lost connection has nothing to do with the signal, or with trying to access another AP, like I mentioned in my comment above.